# R: Parse a line like a shell command line

Tags: r, parsing, command-line, command-line-arguments, tokenize

I have a key=value file like follows:

```
a=foo
b="foo bar"
c="foo \"bar\""
d="foo \'bar\'"
```

Values appear to be quoted/escaped when there are special characters with a logic similar to the shell.
To parse the file into a named vector, the straight way is:

```
txt <- readLines("dat")
spl <- strsplit(txt, "=")
vec <- setNames(sapply(spl, `[`, 2),
                sapply(spl, `[`, 1))
```

which gives:

```
    a               b                       c                     d 
"foo"   "\"foo bar\""   "\"foo \\\"bar\\\"\""   "\"foo \\'bar\\'\""
```

Now, just like for the shell  quotes in `mkdir "new folder"` are not literal, the same is above.
Therefore, I reparse `vec` with:

```
prs <- function(el) if(substr(el, 1, 1) == "\"") eval(parse(text= el)) else el
sapply(vec, prs)
```

That is:

```
    a           b               c             d 
"foo"   "foo bar"   "foo \"bar\""   "foo 'bar'"
```

I wonder if, rather than my naive `prs` function, there is an established one, perhaps from a library, to parse cli-like lines. What I have found so far, assumes R scripts, where `commandArgs()` already makes the tokenising task.